# How to get a chrome tab source code in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I try to develop a chrome extension and I need to be able to get the source code of the current tab, so I follow the chrome example and I have three files:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Source code getter",
    "description": "This extension is a test to get current tab source code",
    "version": "0.1",
    "browser_action": {
         "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }, 
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
  ]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Get source popup</title>
         <style>
             body {
                min-width: 357px;
                min-height: 357px;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
     </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        console.debug(tab.id);
        var source = document.createElement("div");
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "getHtml"}, function(response) {
            console.debug(response.html);
         if (response.html) {
                source.textContent = response.html;
            } else {
                source.textContent = 'I did not get the source code.';
            }
        });
        document.body.appendChild(source);
    });
});
```

I build the popup.js by searching across the web and I must confess I don't really know how the sendMessage works exactly, also with [the doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) but I think the second parameter ask the source code wich must be return in the parameter of function response, but it doesn't, here are the JS log:

```
430 popup.js:4
> Error in event handler for (unknown): Cannot read property 'html' of undefined
> Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined
>    at chrome-extension://boefdmhphdcngpckofecmjnihbgphmch/popup.js:7:35
>    at disconnectListener (extensions::messaging:338:9)
>    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
>    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:397:22)
>    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
>    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatchToListener] (extensions::utils:93:26)
>    at EventImpl.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:379:35)
>    at EventImpl.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:403:17)
>    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
>    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatch] (extensions::utils:93:26)
```

so I got the right tab but i don't get a correct response form sendMessage function, someone can explain me why ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your manifest, you've got nothing listening for your `sendMessage`.

No content script defined in the manifest, so nothing loaded in the page; no `executeScript` calls in the popup code, so nothing gets loaded from there.

So, nothing to process your message, and the callback gets called with an error set. Your message `{action: "getHtml"}` does not magically mean anything; you need a script on the page's side to receive it and form a response.

What you need is a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that will add a listener for `chrome.runtime.onMessage`, that will process your request. Let's call it `content.js`. Then you can do this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "content.js"}, function() {
  if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    return;
  }
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "getHtml"}, function(response) {
    /* process response */
  });
});
```

Code for the appropriate `content.js` is outside the scope of this question. Have a look at the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) too, it's a good introduction of how content scripts work.